# How to link logstash output to spark input

Tags: apache-spark, logstash, elastic-stack

I am processing some logs, I am using logstash to read the logs from log files and filter them before pushing to elastic search db.
However I would like to enrich log information with some data that I am storing in postgres db, so I am thinking of using spark in between.

Is it possible to feed logstash output to spark, then enrich my data and then push it to elastic search

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Use Logstash's Kafka output plugin and read data from Kafka into Spark Kafka receiver and enrich your data. After enrichment you can call the elastic search bulk post documents or single document and index them using REST API.